# How to handle edits with information I can not verify myself

Tags: discussion

I created a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629545/how-to-create-bibtex-entrys-for-web-pages-automatically/629546#629546) here once, to share my efforts on finding a tool to create Bibtex entries from websites.

Now someone anonymous posts an [edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/231414) which adds a new tool and clearly favors this new tool. I did not test that tool so I can not compare it to the previously mentioned ones.

What is the recommended way to respond to such an edit? It could add beneficial information for everyone, but I am unable to verify the credibility of the information myself right now.

A similar [situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101891/can-we-edit-a-post-to-change-its-content) happened before. Answers were positive towards approving the edit, if there was a name to it.

Comment: The edit was approved by Community, obliterating the identify of the original editor.  In my opinion, this is a misuse of the Community bot, and should be reported upstream.  Could this be done by one of the mods, please?  (There was an earlier vote to reject the edit.)

Comment: Thanks, I did not see the vote. Is there anything I have to do right now?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything you can do.  I think we have to trust the mods to kick this upstairs.

Comment: Such a big-list answer like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629545/how-to-create-bibtex-entrys-for-web-pages-automatically/629546#629546 would be ideally suited as "community wiki". Then everybody could edit it and it wouldn't be your "responsibility" that the information is correct.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hm? Normally "approved by Community[bot]" means "the original poster (which is "Paul" in this case)  approves the edit (by clicking some button)". Given the user doesn't really want to here, probably by mistake.

Comment: By the way the *real* issue here is that the question is closed. Probably rightfully. In that case you should delete your answer on the duplicate and move it to the duplicate target (that way, the people who *only* find the duplicate target and not your question will be able to get the information from your answer as well)

Comment: @user202729 There are other scenarios which will also show up as approved by community, e.g. a users who deleted their account in the mean time

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Looking at the specific situation here, we can tell the OP clicked the button "approve and edit" though.

Comment: @user202729 You are right, I edited the post to reflect what I know.

There are two opinions on whether to use community wiki or move the question. If no one objects I would move, so the knowledge is in one place.